# How can I use :^ and :.2f at the same time?

Tags: python

How can I use `:^` and `:.2f` at the same time?

```
txt1 = "For only {:^10} dollars!"
txt2 = "For only {:.2f} dollars!"

print(txt1.format(49))
print(txt2.format(49))
```

I need an output like `"For only 49.00 dollars!"`

Comment: Doesn't your second format string give you the desired result?

Comment: You haven't clearly stated what you're asking for, but [here are the relevant docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).

Answer (score 1):

Use both. :)

```
>>> dollars = 49
>>> f"For only {dollars:^10.2f} dollars!"
'For only   49.00    dollars!'
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you after this?

```
txt1 = "For only {:^10} dollars!"
txt3 = "For only {:^10.2f} dollars!"
print(txt1.format(49)
print(txt3.format(49)
```

Result:

```
For only     49     dollars!
For only   49.00    dollars!
```